# Dialog fragment disappears when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-orientation, dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment that displays a view.  When I show the view it works fine.  Though when I change the orientation of it from landscape/portrait or vice versa, the dialog fragment disappears.  I've tried several suggestions though none have worked.

Here's a condensed version of my Dialog fragment, I've added onSaveInstanceState to save the state, and tried to recall it in the onCreateView.  Though it's not working.
Any advice to help solve this is much appreciated.
Jim

```
public class BalanceOverlay extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {



public BalanceOverlay() {
    // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
    // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
    // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
}

public static BalanceOverlay newInstance(String title) {
    BalanceOverlay frag = new BalanceOverlay();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("Balance - The Center of the Plate", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     bview=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.balance, container);

    //setRetainInstance(true);
    return bview;
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putLong("param", value);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        value =  savedInstanceState.getLong("param");
    }
```

Comment: How do you present the `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Icall this method:
 'private void showBalanceDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        BalanceOverlay balanceOverlay = BalanceOverlay.newInstance("Balance Overlay");
        balanceOverlay.show(fm, "Balance");
    }'

Comment: Looks like your question has an answer - see my link above. It's caused by an issue in the Support library it seems and it was never fixed. Have you tried just removing `setRetainInstance(true)`?

Comment: I commented it out in my code above, though it didn't work.  I did notice, while debug/stepping through it, that my 'onSaveInstanceState (Bundle icicle)' method is never called.  Therefore when it looks for a saved state 'if (savedInstanceState != null)' it's always returning null.  

**Do I have my 'onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle)' method in the wrong location?** As you can see it currently resides inside the base dialogfragment class.  Does it need to be placed within the 'onViewCreated'  or 'onCreateView' methods?  Does it need to be defined differently?

Comment: `setRetainInstance(true)` will make the `Fragment` survive configuration changes, so `onSaveInstanceState` is not called when rotating the screen. It might be called if you move the app to the background and the app is being garbage collected by Android. Have you tried the answer I linked to where `onDestroy` is overridden?

Comment: Ah I see, you outcommented `setRetainInstance(true)`. `onSaveInstanceState` is never guaranteed to be called. Maybe have a look at this post about saving and restoring instance state: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en
There's too much info to fit inside a comment ;-)

Comment: the link was helpful...tonight I will uncommit  'setRetainInstance(true)' and see if it brings the save state back.  I'll update the post with what I find.  thanks for responding!

Comment: I've feel like I've tried everything and I'm not able to get the **onSaveInstanceState** to fire.  I'm open to anymore suggestions if you have them.  thanks.

Comment: Could you post a sample project somewhere so I can try it out, what you're seeing? I can't reproduce the issue from your current code. Also, what is it, that you want to save in `onSaveInstanceState`? A lot of things are automatically saved by the different widgets already.

Comment: Thanks, i'll provide more information tonight.  Though, to re-summarize, I'm showing a custom button , line object, and triangle (using path) on a dialog fragment.  the 3 custom items are replicated several times each.  All that works fine.  When I change orientation the dialog fragment disappears.  While debugging, I noticed the 'onSaveinstanceState was never being called, understanding that some of this might be saved automatically.  On top of that, when I open the dialog back up it looks nothing like what's intended.  Sorry for my ignorance,  aside from here, where can I post some of this

Comment: You can post a project to Github or Bitbucket or if you don't have much code, you can make a Github Gist with the classes and XML then I'll figure the rest out.

Comment: search cop1803e on Github...